# How to identify IoT devices on WiFi network in Rails production app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arduino, iot

I have an IoT project that I have been developing using Rails. I am using ActionCable to manage websocket connections between my app and Arduino devices. The Arduino's are hardwired to ping into the app and join the websocket channel. In development, it is easy because I tell my server to listen to outside requests and the Arduinos ping localhost:3000. Now that I am trying to deploy, I realized it's tricky to manage this in production.

I would like a user to log in and see a list of smart devices in their home, the same way that many market ready devices work. If my app is on Heroku, is there a way I can configure the Rails app to look for incoming requests that share the same WiFi network as the current user? Otherwise, I would need to set up a form on the Arduinos where users would have to input their login credentials for the app to associate devices to users, but from a user experience perspective that would be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to generate and hardcode a unique token in each arduino, put it on a sticker on the device and then ask the users to register their devices.

Or if there is way for them to input the wifi passwords for the local wifi, then you can do any kind of device identification when you show some secret on the website and ask the user to enter it on the device(s).